# Nhibernate one to many relationship composite key issue

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, composite-key

Below is my Parent child relationship class and mapper. We are using Nhibernate 4.0.0.4000 in our project. When I call session.Merge(Parent) to update the parent which has a new child object to insert into Db. It throws cannot insert Null exception for code_column in child object. Can somebody guide which part in my mapper code is wrong?

```
Public class parent {
  public virtual string Code { get; set; }
  public virtual string Desc { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Child> Children{ get; set; } 
  public virtual int version {get;set;}
}

Public class Child {
  public virtual parent ParentObj{ get; set; }
  public virtual string Code1{ get; set; }
  public virtual string Code2{ get; set; }
  public virtual int version {get;set;}
}


public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent> {
public ParentMap () {
   Table("Parent_Table");
            LazyLoad();
            OptimisticLock.Version();

  Id(x => x.Code )
           .Column("Code_Column")
           .Index("Code_IDX1")
           .Length(5)
           .Unique()
           .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
           .Not.Nullable();

            Version(x => x.Version)
                .Column("VERS")
                .UnsavedValue("0");

            HasMany(x => x.Children)
                  .AsBag()
                .KeyColumn("Code_Column")
                .Inverse()
                .LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.All();
}

}


public class ChildMap: ClassMap<Child> {
public ChildMap() {
 Table("Child_Table");
            LazyLoad();
            OptimisticLock.Version();

            CompositeId()
                .KeyReference(u => u.Code, "Code_Column")
                .KeyProperty(u => u.Code1, "CODE1_column")
                .KeyProperty(u => u.Code2, "CODE2_column");

            Version(x => x.Version)
             .Column("VERS")
             .UnsavedValue("0");
}

}
```

Comment: At runtime, does your child object have the correct, non-null, reference to its parent?

Comment: Hello David, Thanks for asking, it was correct at run time.It was the composite Id which had the issue with session.merge method probably because of the lazy load. The below article pretty much explains the issue and resolution. I followed the same by creating a separate class for composite Id and it worked fine. 

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the composite Id which had the issue with session.merge method probably because of the lazy load. When you have composite keys, Create a class for the composite keys and use them in your entity which would work fine.